# Правильно ли я понимаю Adapter, notifyDataSetChanged и назначение паттерна ViewHolder?

Tags: java, android

Дано: некий ArrayList с несколькими объектами одного типа, и Adapter, унаследованный от ArrayAdapter, который презентит эти объекты в ListView.

Требуется: реализовать обновление конкретного объекта, и соответственно обновление соответствующего View в ArrayAdapter.

Я это делал так:

```
arrayList.get(...).setMyProperty(...);
adapter.NotifyDataSetChanged();
```

Правда, сначала почему-то не работало - View не обновлялись.

**Я подумал, что это из-за того, что адаптер как-то сравнивает объекты, а в них у меня нет корректного механизма сравнения**, потому он не обнаруживает изменений и не обновляет соответствующий View, и надо в этих объектах реализовать что-то вроде `hashCode`, `equals` или `comparable`, тогда он будет работать правильно.

Но я нашел решение проще - в свою реализацию ArrayAdapter просто добавить следующее, типа его не хватает:

```
@Override
    public int getCount() {
        return values.size();
    }
```

В результате элемент, действительно, стал обновляться.
*Но ведь у меня по-прежнему нет механизма сравнения, значит, при обновлении одного элемента тупо будет вызываться getView() для всех элементов.*

Я правильно понимаю что это так будет? (чуть позже проверю, просто пока элемент всего 1)

Если понимаю правильно, то нормально ли это, или можно (нужно) как-то реализовать сравнение, чтобы getView вызывался только для вьюшек обновленных объектов?

Еще, как я понимаю, есть паттерн `ViewHolder`, который позволяет в этом случае избавиться от inflate() и findViewById() при каждом обновлении каждого элемента, тем самым хоть и не отказаться от getView для всех элементов, но оптимизировать его.
Но разве не лучше чтобы вообще не вызывать getView лишний раз, а только для обновленных элементов?

Answer (score 3):

> Я подумал, что это из-за того, что адаптер как-то сравнивает объекты, а в них у меня нет корректного механизма сравнения

Нет, адаптер не сравнивает объекты.

> и надо в этих объектах реализовать что-то вроде `hashCode`, `equals` или `comparable`, тогда он будет работать правильно

Для того, чтобы адаптер увидел изменения и обновил данные, эти методы и этот интерфейс не нужны.

> Но ведь у меня по-прежнему нет механизма сравнения, значит, при обновлении одного элемента тупо будет вызываться `getView()` для всех элементов.

Да, будет, и это не из-за того, что у Вас нет механизма сравнения.

> Если понимаю правильно, то нормально ли это, или можно (нужно) как-то реализовать сравнение, чтобы `getView` вызывался только для вьюшек обновленных объектов?

Сравнение реализовывать не нужно. Можно обновить определенные элементы в `ListView`, но это придется делать вручную: проверять, виден ли элемент с заданным индексом, если да, то получать соответствующую `View` и изменять ее вручную (как говорил Romain Guy на Google I/O в далеком 2010-м году, этот способ является самым эффективным для обновления только определенных `View`).

> Но разве не лучше чтобы вообще не вызывать getView лишний раз, а только для обновленных элементов?

Конечно, лучше.

А вообще, посоветую перейти от `ListView` к `RecyclerView`, так как последний является более гибким, оптимизированным и проще кастомизируется (и обязует использовать `ViewHolder`).

В частности, у `RecyclerView.Adapter` есть метод `notifyItemChanged(int position)`, вызов которого влечет за собой перерисовку только определенного `View`.

Answer (score 2):

метод адаптера `notifyDataSetChenged()` просто перечитывает заново все данные из массива (или другого источника списка) и заполняет список по этим новым данным. Он ничего ни с чем не сравнивает и не выделяет произошедших изменений- это не эффективно для такой простой задачи.

метод `getCount()` вызывается адаптером, когда ему необходимо узнать, какое количество элементов будет отображаться в списке. Когда вы вносите изменения список может увеличиваться (добавлены элементы) или уменьшаться (удалены) поэтому при нотификации списка каждый раз запрашивается актуальный размер хранилища данных для отображения. При этом, если метод `getCount()` не переопределен, то адаптер ничего не отображает, так как не знает о новом размере.

> можно (нужно) как-то реализовать сравнение, чтобы `getView()` вызывался только для вьюшек обновленных объектов?

Это совершенно не нужно и даже вредно, так как на самом деле только замедлит работу, а не ускорит ее. Дело в том, что адаптер **не хранит все** представления элементов, а создает их по мере надобности (только видимые в данный момент на экране) - это гораздо эффективнее придуманного вами способа, так как создается всего несколько элементов каждый раз, взамен вычисления изменений для всего набора данных, в которых может быть и сотни и тысячи элементов. Кроме того применяются и другие оптимизации для ускорения вывода - паттерн `ViewHolder`, хранящий ссылки на виджеты и `ConvertView`, хранящий отинлейтеную разметку одного элемента (для списка она чаще всего остается неизменной и нет нужды просчитывать ее каждый раз из XML).
Так же стоит учтывать тот факт, что айтемы в списке постоянно переиспользуются и "пропадающие" сверху появляются внизу (при прокрутке вниз, естественно). Таким образом адаптер на самом деле работает с штучным количеством айтемов (до 8 штук обычно) и подставляет одни и те же, внося только изменения в контент виджетов, в соотвествии с позицией в хранилище данных.

> тупо будет вызываться `getView()` для всех элементов.

да, это так, но для всех **видимых на экране в данный момент** элементов и не более.

> Но разве не лучше чтобы вообще не вызывать `getView()` лишний раз, а только для обновленных элементов?

Лучше в теории, если бы был эффективный механизм определения таких элементов, но виджет `ListView` не обладает таким функционалом. Такой функционал есть в более сложном аналогичном виджете `RecyclerView` - методы [`notifyItemChanged()`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/widget/RecyclerView.Adapter.html#notifyItemChanged(int)) (обновлен один элемент) и [`notifyItemRangeChanged()`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/widget/RecyclerView.Adapter.html#notifyItemRangeChanged(int,%20int)) (обновлен диапазон элементов), но этими виджетами управляет человек (указывает явно, где произошли изменения, так как ему заранее известно, где это произошло, как правило), а не адаптер. Хотя, по большому счету это сделано больше для применения анимации к обновлению элементов, чем в целях какой то значительной оптимизации. Повторю, для адаптера эта работа абсолютно не эффективна и сильно замедлит его работу.